# не отображаются изображения, загруженные paperclip-dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

С помощью гема paperclip-dropbox организовано хранение картинок на dropbox, картинки успешно загружаются, но при просмотре выводятся не сами картинки, а их название.

Вот моя модель:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      validates :name, presence: true

      has_attached_file :avatar, 
        :storage => :dropbox,
        :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
        :dropbox_visibility => 'public',
        # :dropbox_options => {...},
      styles: { medium: "400x400>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "event.jpg"
      validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
    end
```

... контроллер:

```
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end

      def new
        @user = User.new
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          render 'create'
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
      end
```

... и вьюха, перечень юзеров с аватарами передаю партиалом. Сама вьюха:

```
    New user:<br/>
    <%= link_to 'new user', new_user_path %>
    <hr/>
    <%= render partial: 'users/user', collection: @users %><br/>
```

... и партиал:

```
    <%= link_to user.name, user_path(user) %>
    <% if user.avatar != nil %>
      <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %>
    <% end %>
```

Согласно документации хелпер <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %> должен отображать картинку, реально же выводит имя файла. При просмотре страницы как html показывает что не может загрузить файл. Если же работать с гемом paperclip в режиме хранения файла на диске а не в облаке - то все работает.

Что я делаю не так, подскажите!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [README `paperclip-dropbox`](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox):

> This gem is not maintained anymore and became obsolete. Over time Dropbox made some significant changes to its API, which breaks this gem's core functionality.

> Этот гем больше не поддерживается и устарел. Со временем в Dropbox внесли существенные в API, сломавшие основную функциональность этого гема.

Проверяйте даты, читайте документацию. Гем неработоспособен уже с 2015 года.

И раз уж на то пошло, использовать Dropbox для этой цели в целом плохая идея.

Comment: Спасибо. Приблизительно догадывался о подобном, а документацию читал невнимательно.